# creating an image from two separate arrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, colors, python-imaging-library

I have an output array with shape `(2, 6, 4)` that will represent an image file (6x2 pixels)

And I also have one array of `[x,y]` co-ordinates and one array of `[255,255,255]` colour values for each of those co-ordinates.

How can I fill the output array with the colour values in the correct indices, without using a loop to iterate over each to accomplish this?

here is a contrived example:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

xy_coordinates = np.array([[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [5,1]])
colours = np.array([['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255'], ['255', '255', '255']])

output_array = np.zeros([2, 6, 4], dtype=np.uint8)

# fill output_array with elements from colours array in correct indices
# at a loss :(

output_img = Image.fromarray(output_array)
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Surely a (2,6,4) array would represent 4 images of (6,2)? Or is the image 4 channel RGBA or CMYK?

Comment: ah sorry I should have mentioned, yes it is a 4 channel RGBA

Comment: So as your coordinates cover every pixel, you image will end up white everywhere with zero in the A channel. So why not just make that?

Comment: this is a good point but the white colour is just used as an example, the real thing has lots of different colour pixels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
import numpy as np

# Create empty black output image
RGB = np.zeros((2, 6, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

# Coordinates of pixels to change
xy_coordinates = np.array([[0,0], [1,1], [0,4], [1,5]])

# Colours to change them to: Red, Green, Blue Yellow
colours = np.array([['255', '0', '0'], ['0', '255', '0'], ['0', '0', '255'], ['255', '255', '0']])

# Do all the entries
for i in range(len(colours)):
    RGB[xy_coordinates[i][0],xy_coordinates[i][1]] = colours[i]
```

[image]

If you want an alpha channel, you can add it afterwards easily:

```
A = np.zeros((2,6),np.uint8)
RGBA = np.dstack((RGB,A))
```

---

I believe this is equivalent to that whole `for` loop, but am not so sure of myself:

```
out[xy_coordinates[:,0],xy_coordinates[:,1]] = colours[:]
```

Maybe someone smarter than me, i.e. @divakar or thousands of others, can comment/clarify?

Comment: I think your coordinates are in the other order, so you may need `RGB[xy_coordinates[i][1],xy_coordinates[i][0]] = colours[i]`

Comment: thanks Mark.  `output_array[xy_coordinates[:,1], xy_coordinates[:,0]] = colours[:]` is what I needed.